# Unexplained gap between items for visual studio module creation dotnetnuke

Tags: html, asp.net, module, dotnetnuke

I created a linqdatasource connection to my sql server and i load my data inside a listview.
Now for that listview i added another table from the top of that listview like a title.(i also tried div or p)

The issue now is when i add this module to my website there is a gap between the listview and the top item whether its a table or a dive or anything.

Inside visual studio it show fine with no gap. Here is my code:

[image]

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName="MyModules.ProductDetailsModule" Inherits="DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CodingStaff.Modules.MenuBox.Licensing" %>

<script runat="server">
    Dim prodID As Integer
</script>

<%
    prodID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("ProductID"))
%>

<style type="text/css">
    h1 {
        font-family: Lucida Grande;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    td {
        font-family: Lucida Grande;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #999999;
    }
</style>

<table style="width: 704px;">
    <tr style="width: 704px;">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr bgcolor="#e7e7e5" height="35">
                        <td align="left" style="width: 704px;">
                            <h1 style="color: #666666;">Technical info</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PRODUCTID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td runat="server" style="width:352px"><strong>Product Code:</strong></td>
                        <td style="width:352px"><strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTID") %>' /></strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td runat="server" style="width:352px"><strong>Name:</strong></td>
                        <td style="width:352px"><strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTNAMELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTNAME") %>' /></strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td runat="server" style="width:352px"><strong>Description:</strong></td>
                        <td style="width:352px"><strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTDESCRIPTIONLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTDESCRIPTION") %>' /></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table runat="server" border="0" style="">
                        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer">
                            <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="">
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="ProductsModule.ProductsModuleDALDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="PRODUCTs" Where="PRODUCTID==@prodID">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="prodID" QueryStringField="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

And here a similar code with the same issue:

[image]

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="View.ascx.vb" Inherits="DesktopModules_MyModules_ProductsModule_View" %>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSourceProducts" runat="server" ContextTypeName="ProductsModule.ProductsModuleDALDataContext" EntityTypeName=""
     TableName="PRODUCTs" OrderBy="PRODUCTNAME" Select="new (PRODUCTID, PRODUCTNAME)">
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<style type="text/css">
    td   {
    font-family:Lucida Grande;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:15px;
    }
    table{
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
     A{
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    a:link{
    color:#666666;
    }
    a:visited{
    color:#666666;
    }
    a:hover{
    color:#666666;
    }
    a:focus{
    color:#666666;
    }
    a:active{
    color:#666666;
    }
</style>

    <asp:Table runat="server" style="width: 704px;" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="0">
        <asp:TableRow bgcolor="#e7e7e5" height="45">
            <asp:TableCell align="left" style="width: 100%;" >
                <p1 style="color: #666666; font-size:inherit"><strong>Product list</strong></p1>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceProducts" GroupItemCount="4" DataKeyNames="PRODUCTID">
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="background-color: #ffffff;color: #284775;"  width="176">
            <asp:Image  ImageUrl="~/images/drop59.png" ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Commercial-vehicle-lubricants/Product-line/product-details?ProductID=<%# Eval("PRODUCTID") %>" target="_self">
                <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTNAMELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTNAME") %>' /></a>
            <br />
        </td>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="background-color: #FFCC66;color: #000080;">PRODUCTID:
            <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTID") %>' />
            <br />
            PRODUCTNAME:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PRODUCTNAMETextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCTNAME") %>' />
            <br />
        </td>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>
<td runat="server" />
    </EmptyItemTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="">PRODUCTID:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PRODUCTIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCTID") %>' />
            <br />PRODUCTNAME:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PRODUCTNAMETextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCTNAME") %>' />
            <br />
        </td>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="background-color: #ffffff;color: #333333;" width="176">
            <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/drop59.png" ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Commercial-vehicle-lubricants/Product-line/product-details?ProductID=<%# Eval("PRODUCTID")%>" target="_self">
                <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTNAMELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTNAME") %>' /></a>
            <br />
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;font-family: Lucida Grande, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#999999;">
                        <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="text-align: center;background-color: #FFCC66;font-family: Lucida Grande, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #333333; font-size:15px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
         <td runat="server" style="background-color: #FFCC66;font-weight: bold;color: #000080;">PRODUCTID:
            <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTID") %>' />
            <br />PRODUCTNAME:
            <asp:Label ID="PRODUCTNAMELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCTNAME") %>' />
            <br />
        </td>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

UPDATE!!!!!

Ive looked the website from chrome with f12 to see what happens with the gap. Ive notice that on every table declaration a gap is added. here is a sample image. the orange is the gap thats generated and also below Technical info there is a gap again.

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you inspect that gap with Firebug or Chrome dev tools (right click on the gap, click "Inspect Element")?  That should give you some indication of what is producing the gap.

Comment: didnt think of that. ill give it a go tomorrow at work

Comment: Ive looked it from chrome m8 and i noticed that on every <table> declaration there is a gab for some reason. Ive uploaded an image to the thread. You have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to this. I had inside another module in another page a padding top 30px. And as it seems it shares this options to the whole site. So anywhere that a table declaration existed it added a 30px gap on top. I fixed it by making that specific 30px padding with table.aVariableName so that is dinstinct to a specific table only